# Purpose of resistor in open collector

Tags: resistors

I am comparing breakout boards for VL53L0X sensor by different distributors. Below is from Pololu:

[image: Pololu schematic]

What is resistor R7 marked above for? This is not present in Adafruit's schematic.  Also not present in another distributor I bought from. It is present in DFRobot. It is not present in "typical application" diagram from the sensor's datasheet.

I can understand the purpose of R6 pull-up resistor. XSHUT is active low so when nothing is connected, it is pulled up to 2.8V. XSHUT is activated by connecting XSHUT to ground (e.g. via microcontroller output LOW).

Is R7 for limiting current when XSHUT is connected to ground? XSHUT is input for the sensor so I don't think the current is a problem.

Comment: It looks like a protection resistor for ESD.

Comment: R7 doesn't do anything **functional** at all. They are only important for **protection**. If for some reason XSHUT has a voltage higher than VDD or lower than ground, R7 will **limit the current** and prevent damage to the VL53 chip. This can happen during an ESD event as Toor mentiones.

Comment: Forgot to mention: XSHUT and GPIO need this ESD protection because these signals are present on a **connector**. If you pickup the board, you could touch that connector so making the signals on a connector more ESD robust is good practice. Also the VL53 chip will have build-in ESD protection. However adding the 1k resistors doesn't harm and will only help to make things even more robust.